# How to convert List to a Map?

Tags: apex, controller, list, map

I have a `List<custom_object__c>`. I want to convert to a Map, where the ID is the String and the value to be an custom_object__c object.

```
Map<String, WrapperEmployee> mapEmp = new Map<String, WrapperEmployee>();
for(WrapperEmployee emp : WrapperEmployeeList)
{
     mapEmp.put(emp.Name, emp);
}
```

The problem with the above code is that its only adding the last row, so if I have 10 rows in the `WrapperEmployeeList` it only addes in the `mapEmp` the last row from the `WrapperEmployeeList`.

Comment: Do they all have the same `Name`? You must use a unique key.

Comment: they all have the same name

Comment: in case if name is not uniq, you should use **Map<String, List<WrapperEmployee>>**

Comment: @kurunve: if I use the `List<WrapperEmployee>` getting this error `Incompatible value type`

Comment: why do you wanna use map?

Comment: Map<String, List< WrapperEmployee>> mapEmp = new Map<String, List<WrapperEmployee>>();
for(WrapperEmployee mapEmp : WrapperEmployeeList)
{
     if(!mapEmp.containsKey(mapEmp.Name)){
        mapEmp.put(mapEmp.Name, new List<WrapperEmployee>();
    }
     mapEmp.get(mapEmp.Name).add(mapEmp);
}

Comment: You keep using that word (map). I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: @AdrianLarson: it was typo, let me correct that

Comment: @kurunve, post this as answer

Answer (score 14):

You begin your question with:

> I have a List<custom_object__c>. I want to convert to a Map, where the ID is the String and the value to be an custom_object__c object.

Then you show us code that doesn't at all reference `List<custom_object__c>`. So, like others, I'm a bit confused. To help point you in the right direction, I'm going to give you an answer to the the initial question which you can perhaps adapt to your other code.

Assuming you have `List<custom_object__c>MyList`,

```
map<Id,custom_object__c>MyMap = new map<Id,custom_object__c>(MyList);
```

The above automatically creates your map with Id and your object. If you need the Id's explicitly as strings (that's actually what they are), you can create a new map from the above by iterating on the `keyset()` and using `string.valueOf(Id)`.

You'll find the above map constructor and other methods documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_map.htm).